# Access SQL - Order Union Queries Independent of One Another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am automating some pivot tables for our team and have successfully recreated a summary table that is able to grab all pertinent numbers by region and then include a summary row using union with the following code:

```
SELECT region, round(sum(iif([Entered In Portal] = "Y", 1, 0)) / count(*) * 
100,1) & "%" as [% Entered]
from tblITPortalYTD
where [Compliance Reporting Month] = Forms!frmMonth!Month
group by region
UNION ALL 
SELECT "Total" as region, round(sum(iif([Entered In Portal] = "Y", 1, 0))  / 
count(*) * 100,1) & "%" as [% Entered]
from tblITPortalYTD
where [Compliance Reporting Month] = Forms!frmMonth!Month;
```

This works and results in the first query returning ordered by region and the 2nd query appearing appended to the bottom as a summary row. The problem is it would be preferable to have one of the regions appear just above the grand total row (out of normal alphabetic order).

Example: a, b, c, d, e, f, summary --> a, c, d, e, f, b, summary

I attempted to use the ORDER BY IIF(Region = A, 1, IIF(region = B, 2, 3)) methodof ordering, but it doesn't work. If I use this method on the first query alone, the ordering works perfectly, but combining it with a UNION ALL overrides it to its original state.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can turn you current query into a subquery, select from that and order.  select * from (your big union query)a order by region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really order inside of a UNION query. You need to wrap the result set up in a subquery and then order that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT region
        ,round(sum(iif([Entered In Portal] = "Y", 1, 0)) / count(*) * 100, 1) & "%" AS [% Entered]
    FROM tblITPortalYTD
    WHERE [Compliance Reporting Month] = Forms ! frmMonth ! Month
    GROUP BY region

    UNION ALL

    SELECT "Total" AS region
        ,round(sum(iif([Entered In Portal] = "Y", 1, 0)) / count(*) * 100, 1) & "%" AS [% Entered]
    FROM tblITPortalYTD
    WHERE [Compliance Reporting Month] = Forms ! frmMonth ! Month
)subquery
ORDER BY IIF(Region = A, 1, IIF(region = B, 2, 3))
```

Now, though, your total row is not guaranteed to shake out on the bottom. To fix, you could add an ordering column to each query:

```
SELECT region , [% Entered] 
FROM
(
    SELECT region
        ,round(sum(iif([Entered In Portal] = "Y", 1, 0)) / count(*) * 100, 1) & "%" AS [% Entered]
        ,IIF(Region = A, 1, IIF(region = B, 2, 3)) as myorder
    FROM tblITPortalYTD
    WHERE [Compliance Reporting Month] = Forms ! frmMonth ! Month
    GROUP BY region

    UNION ALL

    SELECT "Total" AS region
        ,round(sum(iif([Entered In Portal] = "Y", 1, 0)) / count(*) * 100, 1) & "%" AS [% Entered],
        99999 as myorder
    FROM tblITPortalYTD
    WHERE [Compliance Reporting Month] = Forms ! frmMonth ! Month
)subquery
ORDER BY myorder
```

And tweak as you see fit.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Really simple solution. I had been banging my head against the wall making it more complicated than it needed to be.

edit - the first example worked without adding a sorting column

Comment: I'm glad to hear it did the trick. I wouldn't 100% rely on that first one ALWAYS putting "Total" at the bottom. It probably always will be simply because Access is probably pulling it last and appending it to the recordset, but that's just relying on a bit of luck. `IIF(Region = A, 1, IIF(region = B, 2, iif(region="Total", 99999,3)))` would be safest.